# How to align paragraph with different chunks in iText

Tags: itext, text-alignment

I need help in to Justify the alignment of the below paragraph:

```
Font certifyFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16);
Paragraph certifyParagraph = new Paragraph();
certifyParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);

Chunk certifyText = new Chunk("This is to certify that  ", certifyFont);
certifyParagraph.add(certifyText);

Font nameFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16, Font.BOLD);
Chunk nameText = new Chunk("NAME ", nameFont);

Font workingFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16);
Chunk workingText = new Chunk("has been working in the company since the ", workingFont);

doc.open();
doc.add(certifyText);
doc.add(nameText);
doc.add(workingText);
doc.close();
```

I tried to align the paragraph to justify, center and right, but the alignment doesn’t seem to be reflected in the PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are creating a `Paragraph` object `certifyParagraph` and you are defining an alignment for it, but you are never adding it to the document. Instead you are adding three different `Chunk` objects, named `certifyText`, `nameText` and `workingText`.

I have adapted your code so that these three `Chunk` objects are added to the `Paragraph` object, and so that the `Paragraph` object is added to the document instead of the separate (alignment-less) chunks:

```
Paragraph certifyParagraph = new Paragraph();
certifyParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);

Font certifyFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16);
Chunk certifyText = new Chunk("This is to certify that  ", certifyFont);
certifyParagraph.add(certifyText);

Font nameFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16, Font.BOLD);
Chunk nameText = new Chunk("NAME ", nameFont);
certifyParagraph.add(nameText);

Font workingFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16);
Chunk workingText = new Chunk(" has been working in the company since the ", workingFont);
certifyParagraph.add(workingText);

doc.open();
doc.add(certifyParagraph);
doc.close();
```